# Access files from both server instances

Tags: java, file, jboss

I am uploading files to some location at Jboss server.
The server has two instances ,I monitored that files are uploaded either at Node1 or Node2.

Here If my file download request comes to only Node1 , so file available at Node2 will not be served and vice versa. How to resolve this .

Is there any way by which I can check where my file is and I can redirect my request to that node.

*Note: I cannot have shared drive or common location from where these files can be accessed.*

Answer (score 0):

This question is subjected to the design that you want to follow. Couple of approaches will be

1. If the Server 1 throws a FileNotFoundException, forward same file request to Server 2. If file is available in Server 2, return back the file in the response to Server 1. This takes time, as it has to create an HTTP Connection, wait for the response etc
2. Save the file location / server location, in a DB. Check the DB, before checking for file and do the same as 1.
3. If the applications are based on EJB (you have not mentioned it), then you can make a remote EJB call, which will be faster than HTTP i would reckon.

None of this reduces the file redundancy, space issues though. And I hope there is a good enough reason to not have a shared storage, because the ones said above, just complicates a lot of things like File Handling, Exception Handling, Memory Management etc.